# How can i create a platform independent(Mac OS, Linux, Windows) SDK in c# with an UI ?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, sdk

I need to create an sdk in C# which i need to integrate with Unity Game Studio games.How should i create a ui for this so that i can view and interact to my SDK from inside the game itself.The SDK should be platform independent(Mac OS, Linux, Windows).

Comment: Have you had a look on [Xamrain](https://www.xamarin.com/) and Mono.

Comment: this question is a bit vague, could you post more information regarding what you hope to achieve??